# Include in middle table with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models with many to many relation. UserProject is another model.

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, through: UserProject);
Project.belongsToMany(User, through: UserProject);
```

How can I make an include of User or Project if I search UserProject? For example:

```
UserProject.findAll({ where: { name: 'xxx' }, include: User });
```

I can't do this because UserProject is not associated with User. How can I obtain UserProject instances with User or Project associated instances?

Answer (score 1):

Then the query would look like this.

```js
    const UserProject = sequelize.model(`UserProject `)
    await UserProject.findAll({
        where: {TestColumn: 'abc3'},
        raw: true,
        include: [User, Project]
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

For more details, please check [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html)

The entire example with temp data is next one:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>')

const defineModelsAndData = async () => {
    sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    })
    const User = sequelize.model(`User`)

    sequelize.define('Project', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    })
    const Project = sequelize.model(`Project`)

    await sequelize.define('UserProject', {
        UserId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        ProjectId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        TestColumn: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        AnotherColumn: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    }).sync()
    const UserProject = sequelize.model(`UserProject`)

    User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: UserProject})
    Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: UserProject})

    UserProject.belongsTo(User)
    UserProject.belongsTo(Project)

    await User.sync()
    await Project.sync()

    let jane = await User.create({name: 'Jane Doe'})
    let bill = await User.create({name: 'Bill Conan'})

    let petProject = await Project.create({name: 'petProject'})
    let webSite = await Project.create({name: 'web-site'})

    jane.addProject(petProject)
    bill.addProject(petProject)

    bill.addProject(webSite)
}

;(async () => {
    await sequelize.authenticate()
    await defineModelsAndData()

    const UserProject = sequelize.model(`UserProject `)
    await UserProject.findAll({
        where: {TestColumn: 'abc3'},
        raw: true,
        include: [User, Project]
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
})()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case, I need to search with UserProject (this is an example, I have another middle table with many properties, like name). So I have to search middle table because it have values that I need, but I want to include User and Project too. The only way is after the search, find Users that have the userId of UserProject?

Comment: I tried to update the association to:
`UserProject.belongsTo(User)
UserProject.belongsTo(Project)`

and then the query looks like:
`await UserProject.findAll({
        where: {TestColumn: 'abc3'},
        raw: true,
        include: [User, Project]
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })`

Comment: Yes! This morning a partner found this solution. Please answer with this because is the solution: Add belongsTo to the middle table.
Thank you!!